# Como criar um robô utilizando requisições em Java?

Tags: java, eventos, servidor

Eu tenho me interessado em fazer robôs para realizar pequenas tarefas repetitivas e chatas. Eu utilizo uma classe do `Java` chamada Robot. Entretanto, acho que a maneira que estou fazendo não é a mais adequada, pois é um robô bastante artesanal que trabalha com eventos do mouse e do teclado. Gostaria de desenvolver um baseado em requisições ao servidor (`GET` e `POST` por exemplo), mas não sei que classe ou quais recursos e técnicas utilizar.

Eis um código de exemplo dos "robôs artesanais":

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Robo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException,
            URISyntaxException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        int login[] = {
            KeyEvent.VK_L,
            KeyEvent.VK_O,
            KeyEvent.VK_G,
            KeyEvent.VK_I,
            KeyEvent.VK_N,
        };

        int senha[] = {
            KeyEvent.VK_1,
            KeyEvent.VK_2,
            KeyEvent.VK_3,
            KeyEvent.VK_4,
            KeyEvent.VK_5,
            KeyEvent.VK_6,
            KeyEvent.VK_7,
            KeyEvent.VK_8,
            KeyEvent.VK_9,
            KeyEvent.VK_0};

        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(
                new URI("https://registro.br/cgi-bin/nicbr/login"));
        robot.delay(3000);

        //Login
        for (int i = 0; i < login.length; i++) {
            robot.keyPress(login[i]);
            robot.delay(100);
            robot.keyRelease(login[i]);
            robot.delay(300);
        }
        robot.delay(200);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(1000);

        //Senha
        for (int j = 0; j < senha.length; j++) {
            robot.keyPress(senha[j]);
            robot.delay(100);
            robot.keyRelease(senha[j]);
            robot.delay(300);
        }
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(1000);

        try {
            for (int i = 0, j = 1000; i < 1000; i++, j--) {
                robot.mouseMove(i, j);
                robot.delay(5);
            }
            robot.delay(500);
            //robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            //robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        robot.delay(200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer requisições `HTTP` em Java, é necessário utilizar a classe de conexão HTTP providas pela `jdk`. Um exemplo é a [HttpURLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). Ainda é possível utilizar alguns [pacotes apache](http://hc.apache.org/) destinados para este fim.

Para finalizar, a sua pergunta está um pouco ampla, mas, dependendo do que você queira fazer, talvez java não seja a linguagem ideal para o tipo de tarefa que você quer fazer, talvez uma [linguagem de script](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_script), como [python](/questions/tagged/python), seja melhor para os seus fins, já que a sua intenção é criar **scripts** para realizar tarefas chatas.

Comment: Perfeito. Vou procurar estudar a HttpURLConnection. Era exatamente isto que queria.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode automatizar tarefas dentro do computador utilizando algumas ferramentas.

Eu conheço estas duas ferramentas muito boas para automatizar tarefas, apesar de utilizarem linguagens próprias.

1. [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
2. [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) ( recomendo )

Se você precisa de algo um pouco mais específico você pode utilizar a biblioteca [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Se precisar um controle ainda mais especifico que trabalhe com requisições (GET,POST,PUT etc) e alguma interpretação do html melhor utilizar a biblioteca [HttpCommons](http://hc.apache.org/).